# Navigation bar fixed after scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a navigation bar after header and i want that to be stuck at top of the page while scrolling down.

can i do with **position:relative**?? Unlike position:fixed with the help of  the following script or any other better way?

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
    $('#header').css('top', $(window).scrollTop());
}});
```

here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7HHa5/1/)!

black color background bar to be stuck at the top of the page

please help me out to fix that, thank you in advance.

Comment: Take a look at [StickyJS](http://stickyjs.com/).

Comment: @HashemQolami Thanks for the link, can i use that plugin for a commercial website??

Comment: @HashemQolami It would be more helpful for me without plugin's, is that possible with my given fiddle? please!

Comment: Why can't you simply use `position: fixed;`?

Comment: @Mouagip i have used position:fixed but it isn't moving to the top of the browser getting stuck at the origin location.
And also after zoom-in nav elements are not scrolling vertically with respect to page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/7HHa5/2/) what you're trying to get?

```
window.onscroll = changePos;

function changePos() {
    var header = document.getElementById("header");
    if (window.pageYOffset > 70) {
        header.style.position = "fixed";
        header.style.top = "0";
    } else {
        header.style.position = "";
        header.style.top = "";
    }
}
```

---

**Update:** (I think, not sure) you can't scroll a fixed element, but you can an absolute one. So in the code below we're using `position: absolute` but making it behave like it's `fixed`. Now you can see the `#header` when you zoom in and scroll down.

```
window.onscroll = changePos;

function changePos() {
    var header = document.getElementById("header");
    if (window.pageYOffset > 70) {
        header.style.position = "absolute";
        header.style.top = pageYOffset + "px";
    } else {
        header.style.position = "";
        header.style.top = "";
    }
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7HHa5/4/)

Comment: hey thanks a lot this almost solved what i wanted to. But there is a small problem, the elements of **nav** are missing after zoom-in the page and on scroll.

Comment: @Fastnto `.wrapper` has a fixed width `1000px`. If you change it to `100%` header will fit to the screen. [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7HHa5/3/)

Comment: yeah that will solve my problem but it wont look good as  it completely fill the width of the screen.

Comment: @Fastnto see the update. Not using `100%` on `#header` and you can see the parts that get hidden when you zoom in.

Comment: akinuri! yeah  **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/7HHa5/4/)** is exactly what i wanted to, but again a small problem that i don't know why the header is shaking vigorously while scrolling the page in Chrome, IE and FF. And its fine in safari. That is the only problem i have now and it get's end after that please help me for one last time.
 
And thank you so much for getting me so close.

Comment: @Fastnto It works fine on latest GC and FF. On IE11 it lags. It's not smooth, but it works fine when you change it back to `position:fixed`. But then `#header` will get cut when you scroll. I can't think of a workaround to solve that atm. Maybe you should post another question relating to that problem.

Answer (score -1):

you can solve it with css:

html:

```html
    <nav id= "header">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"> Link 1 </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Link 2 </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Link 3 </a></li>
      </lu>
    </nav>
```

css:

```css
    #header{
    position: sticky;
    top: 0; /* Position where u want it to stick, can be a
               percentage, px, vh or any position unit */
    z-index:150; /* to keep it on top layer in order not to be 
                    masked by another element*/
    }
```

check this link:
https://elextutorial.com/learn-css/css-position-fixed-scroll-sticky/