# Javascript CSS absolute to fixed issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to get an absolute div to become fixed after scrolling town to about 450px. I had something that worked with jquery but it broke half the site due to jquery conflicts. Here is the javascript that I am trying to use

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function window_onload() {
  window.addEventListener("scroll",wallpaper_reset_top,false);
}

var wallpaper_top=450;

function wallpaper_reset_top() {
  var scrollTop=document.documentElement.scrollTop||document.body.scrollTop;
  if(scrollTop>wallpaper_top&&wallpaper.IdName==="wallpaper_absolute") {
    document.getElementById("wallpaper").IdName="wallpaper_fixed";
  }
  else if(scrollTop<wallpaper_top&&wallpaper.IdName==="wallpaper_fixed") {
    document.getElementById("wallpaper").IdName="wallpaper_absolute";
  }
}

</script>
```

this is the set of divs that it is in

```
<div id="body-wrapper">

    <?php if ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) { ?>

    <?php if(get_option('mvp_wall_ad')) { ?>

    <div id="wallpaper">

        <?php if(get_option('mvp_wall_url')) { ?>

        <a href="<?php echo get_option('mvp_wall_url'); ?>" class="wallpaper-link" target="_blank"></a>

        <?php } ?>
```

I'm not really sure where I'm going wrong here, but basically nothing happens when scrolling down

Comment: What do you means about broke half the site due to jquery conflicts? Have you try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20594452/navigation-bar-fixed-after-scroll) post?

Comment: what is wallpaper? I don't understand the wallpaper.idName. Also, you can try using noconflict with jquery, so you'd use (jQuery) instead of "$".

Comment: lazy load stopped working for all of the front page posts. I did try noconflict but that didn't help for some reason. I think it was an issue caused by loading another jquery library. Javascript is more clean and there is a solution posted below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, nice effort on the pure JavaScript!  I'd just change it around a little like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function() {
  window.addEventListener("scroll",wallpaper_reset_top,false);
}

var wallpaper_top=450;

function wallpaper_reset_top() {
  var scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
  if(scrollTop > wallpaper_top && document.getElementById("wallpaper").className === "wallpaper_absolute") {
    document.getElementById("wallpaper").className = "wallpaper_fixed";
  }
  else if(scrollTop < wallpaper_top && document.getElementById("wallpaper").className === "wallpaper_fixed") {
    document.getElementById("wallpaper").className = "wallpaper_absolute";
  }
}
</script>
```

And your HTML:

```
<div id="wallpaper" class="wallpaper_absolute">
```

Comment: I like this correction for this correction, gonna like it, though was waiting from feedback from the OP since I can't test it now.

Comment: Right.  I just changed window_onload to window.onload so that it'll work right out-of-the box.  @ott - if you called that function from elsewhere, this would be unnecessary.

Comment: Also the proper referencing of the className using getElementById.

Comment: perfect! Thank you very much! I get so tired of every answer being "oh use this giant library and add a bunch of overhead to your site"

Comment: No problem! And I agree with you on libraries for simple tasks like this.  Though I'm guessing you're using WordPress so you already would have a noconflict jQuery.

Comment: yup, it's wordpress and I think the theme itself already has 2 libraries for a bunch of other stuff.